# if __dirname gets you the folders your in what gets you the root of the project?

Tags: node.js, electron, absolute-path

Consider the following project structure:

[image]

in `game.js` I have the following:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Loop, Canvas, Sprite}     from '../components/';
import GameLoop           from '../engine/loop';
import path               from 'path';

export default class Game extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log();
    return (
      <Loop>
        <Canvas>
          <Sprite img={'/images/The-Poet.png'} />
        </Canvas>
      </Loop>
    );
  }
}
```

If you look at `Sprite` I am trying to pass in an image, how ever in electron I get the error:

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///images/The-Poet.png`

If I try and use `__dirname` it spits out `src/game/...` I need the absolute path to said image. **Ideas?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build the absolute path by getting the path to the current application directory using app.getAppPath()

http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appgetapppath

Since app is a main process variable and you are wanting this in the renderer process, you will have to require it using remote.

```
var remote = require('remote')
var app = remote.require('app')
```